# How to set option on sphinxapi node module?

Tags: node.js, sphinx

Im using the [node-sphinx](https://github.com/touv/node-sphinxapi) module for node and have it working, but what I can figure out is how to set properties. After looking at the example code:

```
var SphinxClient = require ("sphinxapi"),
    util = require('util'),
    assert = require('assert');

var cl = new SphinxClient();
cl.SetServer('localhost', 19312);
```

I figured you simply used:

```
cl.SetRankingMode(ranker, rankexpr);
cl.SetSortMode(mode, clause);
cl.SetFilter(attribute, values, exclude);
etc...
```

but are not sure what is required, strings, integers, what values or constants like php connectors  etc

Does any have an example using this module?

**EDIT**

I was able to set these properties like below:

```
cl.SetMatchMode(SphinxClient.SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
cl.SetRankingMode(SphinxClient.SPH_RANK_SPH04);
cl.SetFieldWeights({ 'text': 100, 'tags': 200});
```

Text and Tags in the set field weights are fields from database in my index.

Thanks Mark Dickson Jr.

Comment: I don't have any sample code, but while looking at https://github.com/touv/node-sphinxapi/blob/master/lib/sphinxapi.js, there is a pretty big grouping of "constants" starting at line 980.

Comment: Thanks mate, I got to the function definitions but that was it lol, you can set that as the answer and I will update the post with example code for other noobs like me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While looking at http://github.com/touv/node-sphinxapi/blob/master/lib/sphinxapi.js, there is a pretty big grouping of "constants" starting at line 980:

```
// known searchd commands
SphinxClient.SEARCHD_COMMAND_SEARCH     = 0
SphinxClient.SEARCHD_COMMAND_EXCERPT        = 1
SphinxClient.SEARCHD_COMMAND_UPDATE     = 2
SphinxClient.SEARCHD_COMMAND_KEYWORDS   = 3
SphinxClient.SEARCHD_COMMAND_PERSIST        = 4
SphinxClient.SEARCHD_COMMAND_STATUS     = 5
SphinxClient.SEARCHD_COMMAND_FLUSHATTRS = 7

// current client-side command implementation versions
SphinxClient.VER_COMMAND_SEARCH     = 0x119
SphinxClient.VER_COMMAND_EXCERPT    = 0x104
SphinxClient.VER_COMMAND_UPDATE     = 0x102
SphinxClient.VER_COMMAND_KEYWORDS   = 0x100
SphinxClient.VER_COMMAND_STATUS     = 0x100
SphinxClient.VER_COMMAND_FLUSHATTRS = 0x100

// known searchd status codes
SphinxClient.SEARCHD_OK             = 0
SphinxClient.SEARCHD_ERROR          = 1
SphinxClient.SEARCHD_RETRY          = 2
SphinxClient.SEARCHD_WARNING        = 3

// known match modes
SphinxClient.SPH_MATCH_ALL          = 0
SphinxClient.SPH_MATCH_ANY          = 1
SphinxClient.SPH_MATCH_PHRASE       = 2
SphinxClient.SPH_MATCH_BOOLEAN      = 3
SphinxClient.SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED     = 4
SphinxClient.SPH_MATCH_FULLSCAN     = 5
SphinxClient.SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2    = 6

// known ranking modes (extended2 mode only)
SphinxClient.SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25= 0 // default mode, phrase proximity major factor and BM25 minor one
SphinxClient.SPH_RANK_BM25          = 1 // statistical mode, BM25 ranking only (faster but worse quality)
SphinxClient.SPH_RANK_NONE          = 2 // no ranking, all matches get a weight of 1
SphinxClient.SPH_RANK_WORDCOUNT     = 3 // simple word-count weighting, rank is a weighted sum of per-field keyword occurence counts
SphinxClient.SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY     = 4
SphinxClient.SPH_RANK_MATCHANY      = 5
SphinxClient.SPH_RANK_FIELDMASK     = 6
SphinxClient.SPH_RANK_SPH04         = 7
SphinxClient.SPH_RANK_EXPR          = 8
SphinxClient.SPH_RANK_TOTAL         = 9

// known sort modes
SphinxClient.SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE     = 0
SphinxClient.SPH_SORT_ATTR_DESC     = 1
SphinxClient.SPH_SORT_ATTR_ASC      = 2
SphinxClient.SPH_SORT_TIME_SEGMENTS = 3
SphinxClient.SPH_SORT_EXTENDED      = 4
SphinxClient.SPH_SORT_EXPR          = 5

// known filter types
SphinxClient.SPH_FILTER_VALUES      = 0
SphinxClient.SPH_FILTER_RANGE       = 1
SphinxClient.SPH_FILTER_FLOATRANGE  = 2

// known attribute types
SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_NONE          = 0
SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_INTEGER       = 1
SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_TIMESTAMP     = 2
SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_ORDINAL       = 3
SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_BOOL          = 4
SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_FLOAT         = 5
SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_BIGINT        = 6
SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_STRING        = 7
SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_MULTI         = 0x40000001
SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_MULTI64       = 0x40000002

SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_TYPES = [
    SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_NONE,
    SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_INTEGER,
    SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_TIMESTAMP,
    SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_ORDINAL,
    SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_BOOL,
    SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_FLOAT,
    SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_BIGINT,
    SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_STRING,
    SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_MULTI,
    SphinxClient.SPH_ATTR_MULTI64
]

// known grouping functions
SphinxClient.SPH_GROUPBY_DAY        = 0
SphinxClient.SPH_GROUPBY_WEEK       = 1
SphinxClient.SPH_GROUPBY_MONTH      = 2
SphinxClient.SPH_GROUPBY_YEAR       = 3
SphinxClient.SPH_GROUPBY_ATTR       = 4
SphinxClient.SPH_GROUPBY_ATTRPAIR   = 5
```